# Как связать конкретный элемент с конкретной кнопкой если много таких же одинаковых кнопок и элементов JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 квадрата и под каждым есть кнопка. У кнопок и квадратов одинаковые классы, менять их нельзя (новые можно добавлять). Кнопки никак не связаны со своими квадратами. Как мне сделать так чтобы при клике по кнопке менялся цвет только у того квадрата под которым она находится, а не у всех? У меня есть вот такая заготовка кода, но что с этим дальше делать чтобы решить задачу я додуматься не могу) Задачу мне нужно решить на чистом js без Jquery

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const figures = document.querySelectorAll('.figure');

function colorHandler(elem) {
  elem.classList.add('red');
}

buttons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => colorHandler());
})
```

```css
.figure {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <button class="button">Кнопка</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <button class="button">Кнопка</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const containerNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

for (const containerNode of containerNodeList) {
  containerInit(containerNode);
}

function containerInit(containerNode) {
  const figureNode = containerNode.querySelector('.figure');
  const buttonNode = containerNode.querySelector('.button');

  buttonNode.addEventListener('click', (e) => colorHandler(figureNode));
}

function colorHandler(elemNode) {
  elemNode.classList.toggle('figure_active');
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.figure_active {
  background-color: red;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Кнопка</button>
  <div class="figure"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Кнопка</button>
  <div class="figure"></div>
</div>
```